# Induced emf of a moving rod with certain velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

> I am calculating the emf of a moving rod with velocity $v$, given $v$.
>
> [image: 1]

My approach is to multiply
$$Blv$$

Where $l$ is the width and $v$ is the rate of change of the length.
But then I found out there is another formula
$$Bv \ln \left(\frac{\text{distance from cable to circuit} + l}{l}\right)$$

Is my approach correct? or do I need to use the second formula?

Comment: The vBL gives the emf induced between the contact points on the moving rod. You need to check the context and definitions in the other formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the $vBL$ formula is when there is a constant magnetic field. In this scenario, the cable is inducing the magnetic field, so it gets weaker the farther you are from the cable. Thus, $vBL$ cannot be used.

Now, I cannot say whether or not the second formula is correct, but as R.W. Bird said, find its context and definitions to see where it should be used.

---

P.S.

I realize that this would be better suited as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that and nobody else had answered this question, so I decided to help in whatever way I could.

Comment: Thank you so much sir